# Parallel mongoose queries with promises/bluebird?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I have a nodejs/mongodb project using mongoose, and also bluebird for promises.

Here is my problem : I have a function that has to execute sometimes 1 query, sometimes 2 queries in parallel, and then join the result from both queries. Here is a pseudo code (because I use coffeescript, however this isn't related) :

```
function(param) {
  // 1st query
  query1.exec

  // 2nd query, should be done in parallel with the 1st
  if (param)
    query2.exec

  // process requiring result from both queries
  callback()
}
```

I know how to perform parallel tasks with async, however I don't understand how to perform this with bluebird or mongoose promises.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function(param) {
    return Promise.all([
        query1.exec(),
        param ? query2.exec() : null
    ]).nodeify(callback);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I finally managed to make this work. However I did this without nodeify, using bluebird .spread to read results from each promise.

Comment: @Owumaro yes, that is probably better - instead of taking a `callback` return the promise this returns and hook on it from the outside. If you're already using Bluebird there is no point in calling `nodeify` except for exposing things to outside APIs.

Comment: How would you check errors?  What if a query returned a 404?

Comment: @honkskillet with a catch()